# Is there an IDE for java that does not need a compiler like Python?

Tags: java, ide

I'm on a computer that allows the installation of IDEs but not compilers. I want to be able to work on this computer do to ease of access. Is there anything I can do? I would use and online compiler/IDE but that requires constant internet connection and even then it's a hassle when writing a larger program.

Comment: You can just write your code in something like `Notepad++`

Comment: You're going to need a compiler to translate your text into something the JVM can understand.  For online options I'd recommend compilejava.net

Comment: @3kings Notepad++ can edit .java files but it can't be used to compile them into .class files. You would need to use something like javac in the command line for that.

Comment: @KevinKlute Yeah sorry i mis-understood what OP was asking

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE and it also contains its own Java compiler. It's a zip archive that you extract and it only needs JRE (not JDK) to compile Java applications. Is that allowed?

Comment: @Cinnam Eclipse may have it's own compiler, but it still needs a JRE installed to run.

Comment: @Andreas The JRE does not include a compiler.

Comment: @sepp2k I know. What's your point? Eclipse has it's own compiler, so it only needs a JRE, though a JDK is highly recommended, mainly because it includes the source code for the standard Java libraries.

Comment: @Andreas My point is that installing a JRE does not violate the "no compiler" rule because a JRE does not contain a compiler. Therefore installing a JRE should be fine (assuming the OP correctly described the rules governing what's allowed to install). Of course installing Eclipse may violate the rule because it does include a compiler, but that was exactly Cinnam's question.

Comment: @sepp2k Guess I interpreted the question differently, where IDE could be installed because it's just unzip, but JDK could not because that's an installer requiring elevated access, which OP doesn't have. Saying "IDE is ok, compiler is not" sounds like a stupid/misguided *rule*, given that an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) "normally consists of a source code editor, **build automation tools** and a debugger". Unless you're using a script language, a compiler is necessary. --- We'll need OP to clarify what the actual restrictions are.

Answer (score 2):

> allows the installation of IDEs but not compilers

Neither IDE nor compiler need to be "installed".

As an example, Eclipse can be downloaded as a .zip file and simply unpacked. No installation required.

Java, at least the Sun/Oracle version, only comes as an installer, but it doesn't actually need to be "installed". If you can install on another machine, then just zip/copy the files. You just need to add the `bin` folder to your `PATH`.

For Eclipse, you don't even need Java on the `PATH`, just add the `-vm` option to the `eclipse.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.
Java code (.java) is compiled into byte code (.class).
This byte code is then interpreted by the JRE.
The step where the byte code is compiled cannot be skipped because that would violate the nature of the language.
Solutions like online compilers may be your only option.
Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

for running and developing Java applications you need a JVM installed: there is no escape.
If you are in a restricted environment you can install a ["portable JDK"](http://www.brucalipto.org/java/how-to-create-a-portable-jdk-1-dot-8-on-windows/) and then "install" [eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) that is as easy as unzip the archive.

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you won't be able to run python code on such a computer as well. Compiler program(javac.exe) and Interpreter program(python.exe) are both executable files from OS perspective. If you can't install one, same policy/restriction should prevent you to install the other.

One option in this case is to do a ssh (using putty on windows) session to a computer that has java installed. You won't require internet connection in case this other computer/server is in your local LAN/home network.

Comment: The compiler should be javac.exe (java compile), java.exe is what runs the code